# Python: second url in list of urls returns None

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping through a list of urls using beautiful soup.

say I got a list of urls in an array called satellites

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as p
import numpy as np
import requests as r
import json

satellites = [
"https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/insight/in-depth/",
"https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/mars-cube-one/in-depth/",
"https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/osiris-rex/in-depth/",
"https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/exomars-trace-gas-orbiter/in-depth/",
"https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/hayabusa-2/in-depth/"]

# Then my code starts with:

for sat in satellites:
    print(sat)
    page = r.get(sat)
    print("got page")
    soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")
    print("got soup")
```

getting the page content works for the first url, but the second returns None which gives me a traceback 'None' has no attribute 'content'.

I switched the first and second urls around, and the result is the same. All the urls have been tested for being valid and they are.

is there an issue with using requests on a loop over urls?

Comment: What is the value of `satellites`, specifically the one that produces the error? What is `r`? In general, please produce a reproducible example.

Comment: shortened:satellites = ["https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/insight/in-depth/",
"https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/mars-cube-one/in-depth/",
] r is request module. The above urls work perfectly. But it seems when iterating over the list, the second try for request returns None

Comment: I tried to open each of the pages in a browser. They do not exist. Make sure you are not using cached stale versions.

Comment: Seems like the links in my comment have been changed when I pasted them. Try copy pasting the urls in the python code on my question. If I copy/paste them exactly the pages load correctly.

Comment: I've tried adding a config to not keep requests alive s = r.session()
s.config['keep_alive'] = False
 but still no go

Comment: And why is my question voted down? I've edited it so that someone can copy/paste the code and run it on their python session.

Comment: Code worked fine and didn't throw any error. Below is the data from requirements file from virtualenv 
`beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
certifi==2018.8.24
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.7
numpy==1.15.1
pandas==0.23.4
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.19.1
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.23`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/INNh5q5.png Working fine for me. Please check the version you are using

Comment: beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
numpy==1.15.0
pandas==0.20.3
requests==2.19.1
Updated all modules but I still get this error "Object 'None' has no member 'content'"

Comment: I've double checked the list of all modules from the request and all are current versions except for certify, but I can't install it due to python-distributil which installs certify as a package. Here's a dropbox link of the entire script with all the satellites. Can anyone check if they all output properly? https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxftfkl8gw3fm6g/parse_object.rtf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

So after looking into the Requests library docs, I found Session() which keeps one Requests session alive through the entire script.

Tried and it works fine.

So

import Requests as r

s = r.Session()

satellites = [...]

for sat in satellites:
    s.get(sat)

The above does not return None if anything happens. Seems using Requests.get('') directly has issues on some platforms. Mine is currently Mac OS High Sierra. if anyone who said they had no issues are on linux, this might be something platform dependent but I can't speculate.